# Windows Server 2008 R2 boots to mouse

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, black-screen-of-death

Now I know that there is an update for Vista and 7 that causes this problem, but I have tried most of the tips and tricks to fix it on Server 2008 R2 Standard, but it still boots to a black screen with a mouse pointer.  This is only a test server so it isn't important but it would be nice if I could export the data from some of the applications on it.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: And booting into Safe Mode does what?

Comment: Booting into safe mode does the same. I changed the motherboard as I needed more RAM and SATA slots and it seems to have rectified itself. Thankfully I didn't need to reinstall :)